# DevExpress: Adding a revert button to a tab pane

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I have this requirement for a project that I can't seem to think of an idea on how to do it. Basically, I would like to add some kind of revert button beside the header of a DevExpress Tab Pane. I have below a sample image on what I wanted to achieve. Anybody can point me out if this design is possible?

[image]

Comment: This isn't a good idea from UX/UI perspective. Tab pages' only action should be navigation (i.e. close, next...). One thing you could do is show an image in the tab when revert in possible (maybe a red circle) and handle the action of reverting via a button on a page.

Comment: You can also submit a request to DevExpress and they can point you in the right direction.